# Notify myself with message and (optionally) a future point in time

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox

Sometimes I see a question, answer, comment, ... and I don't have time to react immediately. Or someone asks me if I could have a look at something but I'm not at home with access to the required information. (Which is actually what triggered this post)

I think it could be quite convenient if I could leave myself a message with an optional delay, e.g. "remind me in 3 hours" or "remind me at Oct. 1st 2013". The message will then pop up in my inbox so I see it when I come back to SO.

Comment: Google Calendar has event reminders, I believe.

Comment: @DaveChen I tend to forget things. This includes that I starred something, therefore I hope for something which *actively* reminds me. Otherwise I would need SO's inbox, I could just write stuff down somewhere, but when I tried that, I find the note month later and by then it's way too late. I'm aware that not everyone has this problem, but maybe I'm not alone either. :)

Comment: @animuson There are other systems, the point is that SO-related stuff can be done from within. If not that is fine, in which case I could use my smart-phone or any other system available. Maybe that is also what I should do and avoid featuritis on SO :-/

Comment: -1 Nothing personal, I just don't think this is a good feature. If the issue is that users are forgetful, then wouldn't it be in reason to predict they will forget to check the notification telling them not to forget? Aside from that, this feature would buck the conventions used for the notification system on stackexchange. Perhaps as a workaround, use the favorite star, that way you can go to your favorites list and look at the most recently starred post. Otherwise, I am afraid that your memory or other means will be necessary for reminders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whilst this would definitely be handy, it's in the domain of reminder software: to-do lists, an organiser or calendar, etc.

I suggest you find yourself a Calendar or To-Do List application. For example, the Wunderlist to-do service has a plugin for Chrome and Firefox which adds stuff to a Read It Later list - but if you want a reminder, you don't get to add it at the same time (currently).

> *From comments:* There are other systems, the point is that SO-related stuff can be done from within. If not that is fine, in which case I could use my smart-phone or any other system available. Maybe that is also what I should do and avoid featuritis on SO :-/

It *can* be done, but there's not very much gain to having a special reminder system just for SO. Most other reminder systems I've probably used are very good, and unless the SO team gives a lot of attention to this feature, the existing to-do systems I have are going to remain better.

It would be nice, but you're right - adding bits and bobs like this *would* give SO a case of featuritis.

Answer (score 4):

It'll be a lot of work to implement this, considering there are requirements for individual users, storage requirements, automated scripts checking times/dates & issuing messages, maintaining new/old/sent/ready to send, checking if user is online, etc.

Plus the extra potential questions on MSO when it doesn't work, or "how to use it" etc - "I set a reminder for whatever, and didn't get it...and as result my dog died"...

I doubt it'll be a worthwhile project TBH, as I also don't think there will be many people with the need to use it. At least not for genuine Stack reminders, as it's also open to people using it as a reminder for other things, and (likely) reminders for things *away from* Stack while they're at Stack.

> Sometimes I see a question, answer, comment, ... and I don't have time to react immediately.

You could create a new bookmark folder and add anything there you wanted to come back to. It's not ideal as it'll need maintaining, ie once you've actioned a bookmarked question/answer etc remove the bookmark.

As has been said there are many software/etc which provide reminders. Google calender, desktop software etc.

> Or someone asks me if I could have a look at something but I'm not at home with access to the required information

You couldn't utilise a Stack based reminder function anyway, if you don't have necessary access.

To cover all your bases, you'd probs be best checking the available apps for reminders/calenders with events, some will be able to integrate/synchronise between your phone and desktop software (Which Google calender can do).